# Update Explorer configuration without restarting it

Tags: winapi, scripting

I am wondering is there a way to refresh the HKLM registry key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer - without restarting the shell.

I would like to be able to do this without restarting explorer. Is there any known way to do that ?

So far, I found only this thing:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
```

which doesn't work for my case.

It looks insane to me that MS made Explorer so it can't re-read its configuration while running) but you never know.

**EDIT:**
What I try to do is to disable/enable notification area (tray) without restarting.
The registry key is

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\

Variable: NoTrayItemsDisplay

Value: 1/0

**EDIT 2**
This is the source code that supposed to work, but on Vista it doesn't, not for notification area, not for my testing dummy which was MyMusic in startMenu (variable NoStartMenuMyMusic)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   DWORD dwRetVal;

  int  lResult = SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, (WPARAM)0,
                      (LPARAM)"Policy",
                      SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &dwRetVal);

   printf("lResult  = %ld\n", lResult);
   printf("dwRetVal = %ld\n", dwRetVal);

   return 0;
}
```

I tried all sane wparam and lparam values without success. I took the code from [here](http://www.ureader.com/msg/14841591.aspx)
and dude claims it works...

[This article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31604553/getting-explorer-to-rerea.aspx), however, claims that code doesn't work.

Whats even more ridiculous is that [gpupdate](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/refrgp.mspx?mfr=true) is suposed to do the job.

Thx.

Comment: Its not *that* insane. Most apps don't check if a configuration file/registry key has been modified since load, not even Windows itself. Let me guess, you are trying to edit the network settings? I couldn't find a work around for this problem either :S *+1*

Comment: No, I want to disable icon notification on the run.
It IS insane because Explorer is not "most apps", its a freakin Shell :D

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497%28VS.85%29.aspx) message with wparam=0 and lparam="Policy" to the taskbar, not sure if this can be done with scripting

Comment: It doesn't work. I used SendMessageTimeout to send the message and it returns 1 as a result which means it passed OK. However, nothing happens.

Comment: you could try wparam=1 also, check the link, that is how it is supposed to work

Comment: No its not. Applications must send NULL, system sends 1. Anyway, I edited the post and gave C code. Perhaps you can try it yourself.

Comment: Well, you want to emulate the system, so you can't use NULL. If it does not work, it probably means explorer only updates that value on startup

Comment: You need to broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` to all windows (`HWND_BROADCAST`), not just the taskbar, with `wParam=0` and `lParam="Policy"`..