# How to refresh the Windows taskbar after editing the SystemUsesLightTheme registry key?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I'm trying to make an application using the Windows API to change the color theme in Windows 10/11 by modifying the registry values `AppsUseLightTheme` and `SystemUsesLightTheme` under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`.

Now when `AppsUseLightTheme` is changed, either with `regedit.exe` or the `reg /add` command, or even [`RegSetKeyValueW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluew) (from the API), all the open apps automatically refresh their theme.

Changing `SystemUsesLightTheme` however (which affects the taskbar, Start menu, Notification Center, and Action Center), triggers refreshes on all of the above except the taskbar, which remains that way until `explorer.exe` is restarted.

I've tried sending a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message to all top-level windows using [`SendMessageTimeoutW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw), as suggested by [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) himself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406332), but the taskbar still doesn't respect the configuration, even though 1 is returned (which is meant to indicate success).

The only option I have now is to restart the explorer process after the registry value change, but this isn't ideal as:

1. Some explorer windows might be open in the background and restarting would close them.
2. Synaptic trackpad scrolling does not work after explorer is restarted unless another process is killed (usually `syntpenh.exe`) (works for me, but there's evidence that it [doesn't work for everyone](https://superuser.com/q/1147140)).

So is there any other option?

I'm using the [`windows`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/index.html) Rust crate as follows:

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
windows = { version = "0.46.0", features = ["Win32_Foundation", "Win32_System_WindowsProgramming", "Win32_System_Registry", "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging"] }
```

main.rs:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;

use windows::w;
use windows::Win32::Foundation::*;
use windows::Win32::System::Registry::*;
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*;

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut handle = HKEY::default();

        // open the key
        let ret_code = RegOpenKeyExW(
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            w!(r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"),
            0,
            KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
            &mut handle,
        );

        if ret_code.is_err() {
            println!("{}", ret_code.to_hresult().message());
            return;
        }

        // write the value
        let buf: [u8; 4] = 0u32.to_le_bytes(); // 0 for Dark, 1 for Light

        let ret_code = RegSetKeyValueW(
            handle,
            None,
            w!("SystemUsesLightTheme"),
            4,
            Some(&buf as *const _ as *const c_void),
            4,
        );

        if ret_code.is_err() {
            println!("{}", ret_code.to_hresult().message());
            return;
        }

        println!("Done changing");

        // send message
        let ret_code = SendMessageTimeoutW(
            HWND(0xffff), // HWND_BROADCAST
            WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
            WPARAM(0),
            LPARAM(w!("Policy").as_ptr() as isize),
            SMTO_BLOCK,
            5000,
            None,
        );

        println!("{}", ret_code.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: As Raymond Chen also repeatedly suggested, the registry is not a programming interface. The official way to make those adjustments is by going through the system-supplied Settings application. Those changes are intended to be made by a user, not a program.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand that, but I can't go through Settings as I'm trying to automate the theme-switching with the program.

Comment: There is no public, supported API for that. If you are determined to that regardless, you'll have to do it the hard way, reverse-engineer the Settings application, and replicate what it does. And update your application, whenever the Settings application changes.

Comment: Ok if MS tells you something is not possible because the user should be respected, I would say you can be 100% sure it is a lie. Because no one respects user decisions less than Microsoft. See Edge Default Browser shenanigans, the reset of the search bar behavior in Win10 recently, all the icons in the taskbar they force upon users and many more. Even in this case if a user has a dark taskbar in Win10 and upgrades to Win11 it will not be dark anymore.. So if we want consistent behavior for our users we HAVE to do correct programatically. Please don't tell people it should not be done....